# Implement Dynamic textviews inside Asynctask 's onPostExecute method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am downloading some data from the internet in an **Asynctask** class.
So for that i am using **doInBackground** function. 
After this function is executed i am returning the value to **onpostexecute** method.

In this **onpostexecute** method 
i need to make dynamic textviews.

P.S: I am getting all the data in my for loop, i am not getting any errors, i just cannot form the dynamic textviews.
This is my code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //Links.setText(file_url);
            int iterator=0;

            Elements linksText = doc.select("#chapters .tips");
            for (Element link : linksText) {
                  link_link = link.attr("href");
                  narutoLinks[iterator]=link_link;//from latestlinks
                  System.out.println("narutoLinks[iterator]= "+iterator+" "+link_link);

                  link_Text = link.text();
                  narutoLinkHeadingName[iterator]=link_Text;
                  System.out.println("narutoText[iterator]= "+iterator+" "+narutoLinkHeadingName[iterator]);
                  iterator++;
                }
            System.out.println("iterator= "+iterator); 

             TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[iterator];

            for( int i = 0; i < iterator; i++) {
                   textViewArray[i] = new TextView(narutoLinksOnly.this);
                   textViewArray[i].setText(narutoLinkHeadingName[i]);
                   textViewArray[i].setId(i); 
                   textViewArray[i].setTextColor(0xff000000);
                   textViewArray[i].setTextSize(20);
                   textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);


                   textViewArray[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                   ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(textViewArray[i]);

                }


            System.out.println("senkai"); 
            if(connectionTimeout==true)
                {showToast("Connection Timeout");
                 connectionTimeout=false;
                }
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard

        }
```

and this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/Ivory"
    android:id="@+id/dynamicTextview1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNarutoLinksOnly"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout
```

This is how my **oncreate** method looks like:

```
 View linearLayout;//declaring it inside the class itself

    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.narutolinksonly);
        linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.dynamicTextview1);
        initialize();
        new DownloadLinksFromURL().execute(url);
        System.out.println("inside on create"); 
    }
```

1. Am i missing something in my code?
2. Also what is the best way to achieve dynamic textview after getting data from an Asynctask class?

Kindly help.

Comment: @NKN  I am not getting any errors. It's just that i am not able to display the dynamic textviews somehow

Comment: what is "dynamic" text view? how it differs from a normal text view?

Comment: @pskink Dynamic textview is a textview  created during runtime. The static textview is created in xml file.

Comment: your ScrollView fills the height of the LineaeLayout, thats why you see no TextViews

Comment: Any `View` related activity should be done within the `Activity` where it's destinated (even if onPostExecute() is called within it). I'd create that `Array` of `TextView`s, pass it to the `Activity` via a `Message` using a `Handler` and process it there. The way you're facing this leads to lots of problems (and probably yours is related to this).

Comment: How many textview do you get?

Comment: @BoyLittUp btw you can use hierarchyviewer to see how your views are laid out

Comment: @pskink Yes, ScrollView fills the height of the LinearLayout, thats why i couldn't see TextViews. Now after making the android:layout_height="wrap_content" in the code, i can display the textview. However, the page isn't scrolling. The page should scroll as i am putting the textview inside Scrollview in the XML file. I wonder what i am doing wrong.

Comment: add a LinearLayout to the ScrollView and add your TextViews to that LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

use a `listview` instead.

And set an array adapter to it with the list of string that you get from the server.

But in your case try:

```
  textViewArray[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Actually in the past i have used similar way for getting the dynamic textview,however i was not using Asynctask class and doing everything on the main thread itself. However, my projects needs to be implemented using the above format only. Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

you have to setup a listview adapter.  You have the data, but nothing on your onCreateView ties that data to a listView.

Here's an example from the Android site on an adapter using cursors

```
    String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

    // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
    // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            fromColumns, toViews, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Trade their cursor data in for your textViewArray data and make it a BaseAdapter or similar and you're done